# Data Compare Build Task to generate delta insert script for selected tables

Tags: sql, database, tfs, msbuild-task

I want to automate the process of delta insert script creation for master table by comparing development Database to production database.

Have used this tool "Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition Power Tools".

This is the syntax that can be used to compare two databases and generate the delta insert script.

```
MSBuild /t:SqlDataCompareTask /p:SourceConnectionString=”ValidConnectionString1” /p:SourceDatabaseName=”DatabaseName1” /P:TargetConnectionString=”ValidConnectionString2” /p:TargetDatabaseName=”DatabaseName2” /p:OutputPath=”FullPathForDataCompareReults” /p:OutputFilename=”FilenameForDataCompareResults”
```

Now what i am looking for is a way to pass table names, and only these tables should be considered for generation of delta insert script.

If any of you had tried simillar thing let me know what is the alternate approach that you took.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative: redgate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/).

Comment: Is it possible to call this tool from tfsbuild project.

Comment: Yes, this is possible via its command line. See http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content?p=SQL%20Data%20Compare&c=SQL_Data_Compare/help/8.1/SDC_CL_SelectingSingleTablesForComparison.htm&toc=SQL_Data_Compare/help/8.1/toc1318668.htm